# Очистить значение в элементах определенного класса

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно почистить все элементы:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("message-class");
    for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
        elements[i].value = "";
    }
```

Примеры элементов:

```
<span class="label label-warning message-class"></span>
<span class="label label-success message-class"></span>
```

Как бы `$(".message-class").html("");` работает как нужно, а можно на js так же сделать?

Comment: Вместо `value` используйте `innerHTML`.

Comment: _"можно на js так же сделать?"_ - библиотека jQuery написана на JS, так что всё что в ней есть можно сделать и просто на JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('message-class');
for (let item of elements) {
  item.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<span class="label label-warning message-class">ыва</span>
<span class="label label-success message-class">цкцукцук</span>
```